# Webdriver:Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with.

Tags: java, webdriver, element, visible

On my web-page i have a username dropdown list when we take the mouse over it we get the logout option and then only user is able to logout. While automating, as the logout link is hidden, webdriver is not able to interact with it. Please suggest some solutions.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `Actions` class to mousehover and then, when the logout link is visible click on it. You can use the below code for reference.

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
//for hovering over the username field
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("username"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
//for clicking the logout link
WebElement logoutLink = driver.findElement(By.linkText("logout"));
logoutLink.click();
```

Comment: Hi HemChe thanks for the reply...I tried the above code but still im getting an error that " Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Sign Out"} " .

Comment: Hi Hemche, The above code is working fine for moving the element to username link,however it is not able to click on the Sign out link. It is still giving tha same error.